# How to register my service as a global service or how can I use MEF in my scenario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx

I would like to create my own service with global visibility. To implement that, I followed [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Reference-Service-VS-2013-5249e0a5#content) sample solution.

Everything goes well, I can call my service within a class, which extends from the Package abstract class, in this way:

```
public class ClientPackage : Package
{
   private void GetGlobalServiceCallback(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
      IMyGlobalService service = GetService(typeof(SMyGlobalService)) as IMyGlobalService;
   }
}
```

Because I'm in a Package, I can easily call GetService and I can get my service. But what about if I want to get my service from a class, which is not extends the Package abstract class?

For example, I have a class, which implements an ITagger interface. If I want to get a service in this class, I have to use Package.GetGlobalService() method in this way:

```
var txtMgr = (IVsTextManager)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
```

I tried to get my own service with the Package.GetGlobalServie(), but I always getting null. The linked sample code doesn't contain a soluiton for my problem.

May I missed something or I have a wrong scenario to get my service?

EDIT:

Okay, let's say I have to use MEF to get my service, because I can't get my service with Package.GetGlobalService().

I have a solution with 2 projects in it. One is a class library, which contains an interface like this:

```
public interface INamesAccessor
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetNames();
}
```

The other project is the VSPackage (has a reference with the first project), which implements my interface as well:

```
[Export(typeof(INamesAccessor))]
public sealed class BitbucketExtensionPackage : Package, INamesAccessor
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _names { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        return _names;
    }
}
```

Let's say that if the user clicks a given menu under the Tools menu, the logic set the value of the names. Until that the _names is empty.

I would like to use the content of this _names list at my provider, like:

```
[Export(typeof(ITaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TagType(typeof(CommentTag))]
internal sealed class CommentTaggerProvider : ITaggerProvider
{
    [Import]
    public INamesAccessor _namesAccessor { get; set; }

    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");

        return buffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(() => new CommentTagger(buffer, _namesAccessor )) as ITagger<T>;
    }
}
```

I get the namesAccessor here, but every fields are null, the _names IEnumerable also.

Is there a way to force the MEF to import my accessor again when the user click to the menu button? What did I wrong?

Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: Why not use MEF instead?

Comment: Can I use MEF in my case? But how? :-S

Comment: Just export your services with `[Export]`, then `[Import]` them into your other MEF-exported services.

Comment: I tried, I updated my question.

Comment: You should do everything in MEF services, and move all logic out of the Package class (MEF makes composition much easier).  The Package class should get your service instance from MEF using SComponentModel, and call a method to start it up. See http://blog.slaks.net/2013-11-10/extending-visual-studio-part-2-core-concepts/#working-with-vspackages

Comment: For example, https://github.com/SLaks/Rebracer/blob/master/Rebracer/RebracerPackage.cs#L86-L95 http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/SLaks/Rebracer/Rebracer/RebracerPackage.cs#86

Comment: Thanks. Please add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use MEF to composes services for your extensions; not the old COM-based ServiceProvider stuff.

Put all of your actual code in MEF-exported classes, then invoke them from the package class using the `SComponentModel` service.

For more information, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-11-10/extending-visual-studio-part-2-core-concepts/#working-with-vspackages).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  How do you "invoke them from the package class using SComponentModel service?"  your blog shows how to get the component model.  But how do you get a particular MEF component from that?  Import/Export does not work from the VSPackage class

Comment: Nevermind, I missed your comment above on the original topic question.  I can't wait to try this approach out!