# Visual Studio Extension - Registering a new service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vssdk

How do I make sure my service gets registered in the `AsyncPackage` of my Visual Studio extension? I have been following a sample from [VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/AsyncPackageMigration/src). I have also taken a look at how other extensions do it. I tried to do the same yet I cannot obtain my service from global service provider.

Steps I did:

- `[Shell.ProvideService(typeof(SMyService), IsAsyncQueryable = true)]` for my async package class
- `[Guid(...)] interface SMyService { }` defined interface in a new file
- `public class MyService { }` as service implementation. It is created by `CreateServiceAsync` method
- `var container = (Shell.IAsyncServiceContainer)this; container.AddService(typeof(SMyService), CreateServiceAsync);`  inside of `AsyncPackage.InitializeAsync` method before calling `base.InitializeAsync`

Is there something I am missing to make my service accessible from other VS Extextension services?
When I Do `AsyncServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(SMyService))` inside of say MEF component method I get a null.
Do I need to register the service anywhere else?

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194968/how-to-register-my-service-as-a-global-service-or-how-can-i-use-mef-in-my-scenar).

Comment: My problem is I absolutely have to register the service the old way. The service I am trying to extend uses `serviceProvider.GetService(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(...))` to obtain the dependancy I am triing to provide. So I need to pass a guid  to the parent service and provide my service identified by the guid.

Comment: May you get some help from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-troubleshoot-services?view=vs-2019). And perhaps you're using an old version of VS? As I know, the behavior of VS extension differs in different versions, could I know what's the version you use, it would make great help for trouble shooting... :)

Comment: I am using 16.2.5 and 15.9

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about `My problem is I absolutely have to register the service the old way.` Since you're using VS2019, why do you need to register the service in an old way?